# Configure different set of keyboard shortcuts for copy/paste in Photoshop (WIN)

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop

Being left-handed, I use the mouse in my left hand. In most applications I use Ctrl + Insert or Shift + Insert to copy and paste (with my right hand).

For some bone-headed reason, this is not supported in Photoshop, so I have to use right-click > Copy sub-menus, which is a lot slower.

Is there a way to configure Photoshop to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste?

**EDIT: I tried editing keyboard shortcuts, but it will not accept CTRL + INSERT as a valid entry.**

Is there no valid option for left-handed users?

[image]

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: actually, by his shortcuts, it is probably Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free utility [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can [remap keyboard input](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) to achieve the effect you are looking for:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (copy) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste).

*Note this does not affect the CTRL+C/CTRL+V shortcuts; you can continue to use them.* Here is the script that does it:

```
^Insert::^c
+Insert::^v
```

Just [install AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoHotkey104805_Install.exe) and copy the script above into the notepad window that opens at the end of installation. This is the default AHK script that runs when AHK is started. Restart AHK to ensure the modified script is active.

- This remapping will be globally effective for all applications. This is probably a benefit for you, since you don't have to configure each application separately. However, it is possible to modify the script to limit it to only certain applications.
- AHK can actually intercept any keypress combination and send any keypress combination, as well as [many more things](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/index.htm).

Comment: Sadly, Adobe totally fails in this department.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the "Edit" menu, and choose "Keyboard shortcuts", you'll be able to edit the shortcuts by making your own set.

Comment: One would expect this to be a valid solution, but there seems to be a special place in Photoshop hell for left-handed people. See my edits.